# How to print html without breaks using python, beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying print html using beautifulsoup like this:

```
load = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(load, 'lxml')
characteristics = soup.find('table', { 'class' : 'characteristics-table'})
print characteristics
```

Get this:

```
<table class="characteristics-table">
<tr class="characteristics alt">
<td class="name">
Zīmols
</td>
<td>
Emporio Armani</td>
</tr>
<tr class="characteristics">
<td class="name">
<b>Mehānisma tips</b>
</td>
<td>
<b>Mehāniskie automātiskie</b></td>
</tr>...
```

But need something like this:

```
<table class="characteristics-table"><tr class="characteristics alt"><td class="name">Zīmols</td><td>...
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
''.join(characteristics.split('\n'))   #or \r\n on Windows
```

Comment: returns: ''.join(characteristics.split('\n'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: In your code, the type of your variable characteristics is 'bs4.element.Tag'. As with aneroid's answer above: you need to convert it to a string first.  So do:       ''.join(str(characteristics).split('\n'))

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the newlines in `characteristics`, then use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to remove them, by replacing newlines with an empty string `''`:

```
print str(characteristics).replace('\n', '').replace('\r\n', '')
```

The first one replaces unix-style newlines and the second one, applied to the result of the first, replaces windows-style newlines.

Edit: the `.replace` has to be applied to the `str()` of the returned obj from beautifulsoup's find.

Comment: returns: characteristics.replace('\n', '').replace('\r\n', '')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable